# Phusion Passenger + Rails App: website is under heavy load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I have rails app running on passenger web server. From time to time I get queue full error from passenger.

But I have no idea what could cause this problem, because there is no long running requests in production log, nor could I see anything like this in the new relic monitor.

There are no memory leaks also, memory and cpu consumption is like average stats. Any ideas how to debug this situation?

I know about passenger-status --show=requests flag but, it is a little helpful because I don't know what requests it includes: only queued or running (hung) ones also?

Comment: Please set your log level to 7 (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--log-level-log_level) and include a log and your config.